# Printer properties of network printer (SAMBA) takes a long time to load on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, printer, samba, network-printer

Whenever I open the printer properties of a shared SAMBA printer (to change the paper size, orientation, print quality, etc.) the dialog box takes a long time (approx. 1~2 second "choking" delay) to load. During this time, I'd notice the hard disk of the SAMBA print server to light up continuously for the same duration (1~2 seconds). It seems that the loading of the network printer properties dialog box on Windows 7 waits/retrieves something from the SAMBA printer server before loading.

Questions:

1. Why does the loading of the print dialog box depend on the SAMBA print server?
2. How to avoid this delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work via:

**sudo vi /etc/samba/smb.conf**
and adding the following

```
[printers]
use client driver = yes
```